# Enumeration class in physical data model

Tags: database-design, relational-database, uml

I have created an UML class diagram of my DB for a food delivering business. I am using 3 `<<Enumeration>>` classes there. Now I would like to create a physical data model for that DB, so I can move forward to build actual MySQL DB based on that physical data model.

**The problem is I don't know how to draw an equivalent for `<<Enumeration>>` classes in physical data model. Do they look like any other table?**

Below you can see a piece of my UML class diagram with 3 `<<Enumeration>>` classes.

[image: part of my UML class diagram]

Comment: The literals in the enumeration do not have a visibility. You need to remove the `+` symbol in front. (See also p. 168 of UML 2.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**!!! UPDATE**

**Back in 2009** by using a data modelling software named Toad Data Modeler You could do this:

```
                Order
-----------------------------------
PK  order_id : integer
    datetime_order_taken : date 
    datetime_order_completed : date
    total_order_price : long
    order_details : string
    payment_method : enum('cash','credit card')
    payment_status : enum('paid','waiting for delivery','not paid')
            etc. ...
```

**Now**, modern data modelling tools do not anymore let you specify an enum type for a field. Instead, you create a lookup (reference) table with all values possible for that field and link it with field's table - like this:

```
               Order
-----------------------------------
PK  order_id : integer
FK  payment_method_code : integer
             etc. ...




        Ref_Payment_Method
-----------------------------------
PK  payment_method_code : integer
    payment_method_decription : varchar(30)
```

Then you need to fill in all Payment methods that are possible into Ref_Payment_Method table (so called a lookup/reference table)

```
                     Ref_Payment_Method
    =====================================================
    payment_method_code    |    payment_method_decription
    -----------------------------------------------------
         1                 |          cash
         2                 |       credit card
```

Comment: So far as I know ENUM is not an ANSI compliant construct for RDBMSs. I believe the typical implementation pattern is a lookup table. Don't ENUMs also require an ALTER statement to amend them?

Comment: Yeah, that is true. It's been a long time since I used the Toad Data Modeler tool to create data models. Back then (in 2009) you would create an enum typed domain and select it for an attribute within your table. And the final model would look exactly like I described above. Here is a proof : https://community.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-modeler/f/30/t/2179

. Now things are changed and instead of specifying enum type within a table you should use a lookup (ref) table (as you pointed out)